# Wine & Brainyoo2: Cant launch programm

Tags: 18.04, wine

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

I installed the newest version of WINE yesterday with this [tutorial](https://vitux.com/how-to-install-wine-on-ubuntu/) and installed the program `Brainyoo2.exe` with the "standard" procedure: *open with* -> *wine*.

Seemed everything worked fine and I got 2 Brainyoo2 symbols in my application menu: *Brainyoo2* and *Brainyoo2 deinstall*.

Now when I wanna start Brainyoo2 with this Symbol, nothing happens, except I can see in the system monitor that the process is running.

I tried to open the programm with this terminal command line:

```
wine "c:\Program Files (x86)\Brainyoo2\Brainyoo2.exe"
```

and then this bug report appeared:

```
0031:err:winediag:SECUR32_initNTLMSP ntlm_auth was not found or is outdated. Make sure that ntlm_auth >= 3.0.25 is in your path. Usually, you can find it in the winbind package of your distribution.
0031:fixme:file:FindFirstFileExW flags not implemented 0x00000002
0031:fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW ((null),0,0x33f074,0x00000000), stub!
0031:err:wgl:X11DRV_wglCreateContextAttribsARB Context creation failed (error 1)
0031:err:wgl:X11DRV_wglCreateContextAttribsARB Context creation failed (error 1)
0031:err:wgl:X11DRV_wglCreateContextAttribsARB Context creation failed (error 1)
0031:err:wgl:X11DRV_wglCreateContextAttribsARB Context creation failed (error 1)
0031:fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW ((null),0,0x33f064,0x00000000), stub!
0031:fixme:dxgi:dxgi_check_feature_level_support Ignoring adapter type.
0031:fixme:winediag:dxgi_check_feature_level_support None of the requested D3D feature levels is supported on this GPU with the current shader backend.
0031:fixme:msvcp:_Locinfo__Locinfo_ctor_cat_cstr (0x33f688 1 C) semi-stub
0031:fixme:msvcp:_Locinfo__Locinfo_ctor_cat_cstr (0x33f478 1 C) semi-stub
0031:fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW ((null),0,0x33f234,0x00000000), stub!
0031:fixme:d3d9:d3d9_device_CreateTexture Resource sharing not implemented, *shared_handle (nil).
0031:fixme:file:FindFirstFileExW flags not implemented 0x00000002
0031:fixme:file:FindFirstFileExW flags not implemented 0x00000002
```

I only understand that I need the wine version 3.0.25, I have 3.0.4. 
So do I have to downgrade it? Or other ideas?

---

I installed wine 4.0 per terminal. Wine is working fine, but brainyoo isn't... Same problem: Process is running but there isn't a programm window...

Bug report from the terminal:

````
0009:fixme:file:FindFirstFileExW flags not implemented 0x00000002
0009:fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW ((null),0,0x33f074,0x00000000), stub!
0009:fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW ((null),0,0x33f064,0x00000000), stub!
0009:fixme:winediag:wined3d_select_feature_level None of the requested D3D feature levels is supported on this GPU with the current shader backend.
0009:fixme:msvcp:_Locinfo__Locinfo_ctor_cat_cstr (0x33f688 1 C) semi-stub
0009:fixme:msvcp:_Locinfo__Locinfo_ctor_cat_cstr (0x33f478 1 C) semi-stub
0009:fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW ((null),0,0x33f234,0x00000000), stub!
0009:fixme:d3d9:d3d9_device_CreateTexture Resource sharing not implemented, *shared_handle (nil).
0009:fixme:file:FindFirstFileExW flags not implemented 0x00000002
0009:fixme:file:FindFirstFileExW flags not implemented 0x00000002```


Any ideas or should i give up?
````

Comment: 3.0.25 > 3.0.4, it's seems more like an upgrade needed instead of downgrade (25 > 4)

Comment: So you can try to use `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` to update your packages

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
I updated all my packages, but wine is still 3.0.4. This is the reason why i thought i have to downgrade it, because im allready up to date...

Comment: I don't think so, just check the [wine website](https://www.winehq.org/), you would see that lattest wine version is ... 4.0.3

Comment: your wine repository probably stopped to support wine

Comment: Yeah i found "wine-platform-4-stable" in Ubuntu software and installed it, but this version appears nowhere... I can not find it with the terminal nor in the application menu or with "open with another application"

Thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: question is up to date